# Wygwam 'read more' option without new paragraph tags

Tags: wygwam

I am using the wygwam add on, and clicking the "read more" icon to create an excerpt. However, whenever I do this, it creates a paragraph tag around the text before the read more and starts a paragraph tag for the text after the read more. For instance, when I click view source, I see this:

```
<p>some text</p><!--read_more--><p>some more text</p>
```

I can view source and remove that /p before and p after, and that works fine. But if I wanted to stick to WYSIWYG, how do I eliminate those paragraph breaks. What I essentially want is a solid block of text without paragraph breaks when the extended portion is showing.

Comment: What happens if you place the `read_more` within a single `<p>` tag pair? As in don't end the tag before and re-start it after the `read_more`? Thus `<p>some text<!--read_more-->some more text</p>`

Does that address the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work as this is a special feature of Wygwam but try using a soft return (SHIFT+RETURN) instead of a hard return. This will use a 
 tag instead of a

tag pair.

Of course, this will still cause a new line but you might be able to mitigate that via css by setting the 
 tag to be inline.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, foamcow.. the soft return solution didn't work, but your mention of CSS was useful. I ended up being able to work around the extra p tags... they're still there, but I'm using CSS to style it as if they aren't there. Thanks!